# In a template argument, what rules allow the compiler to infer the number of items of an array?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++17, language-lawyer

Given the two programs bellow -- identical except for the definition of the template function `len()`:

```
// ================================
//  a.cc
// ================================
#include <iostream>

template<class T, std::size_t n>
std::size_t len(T (&v)[n]) { return n; }

int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 1,2,3 };

    std::cout << len(arr) << std::endl;
}
```

```
// ================================
//  b.cc
// ================================
#include <iostream>

template<class T, std::size_t n>
std::size_t len(T v[n]) { return n; }

int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 1,2,3 };

    std::cout << len(arr) << std::endl;
}
```

When using g++, the first program compiles and runs as expected. But the second does not compile. Here is the diagnostic:

> ```
> b.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
> b.cc:13:25: error: no matching function for call to ‘len(int [3])’
>      std::cout << len(arr) << std::endl;
>                          ^
> b.cc:7:13: note: candidate: template<class T, long unsigned int n> std::size_t len(T*)
>  std::size_t len(T v[n]) { return n; }
>              ^
> b.cc:7:13: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
> b.cc:13:25: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘n’
>      std::cout << len(arr) << std::endl;
> ```

Why is the compiler able to infer the number of items in the array in the first case but not in the second? What makes, in the C++11 or C++17 standard, mandatory to write `T (&v)[n]` instead of `T v[n]`?

Comment: I'm not going to look for a reference (since I feel it's a fairly well-known fact), but `T x[N]` in a function parameter is completely, exactly equivalent to `T *x`.

Comment: ... but `T(&x)[N]` is not equivalent to `T * const  (&x)` ?!?

Comment: No, this rule doesn't apply recursively. It only applies to arrays. `T x[N]` is an array, so it applies to it, and `T(&x)[N]` is a reference rather than array, so it doesn't apply (a reference to an array, yes, but it doesn't matter what it's a reference to).

Comment: I think I see what you mean. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Template argument deduction is covered by [[temp.deduct]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.deduct) [**emphasis** mine]:

> /1 When a function template specialization is referenced, all of the
> template arguments shall have values. **The values can** be explicitly
> specified or, **in some cases, be deduced from the use** or obtained
> from default template-arguments.
>
> /2 (... regarding explicit template argument list: not relevant here)
>
> /3 After this substitution is performed, the function parameter type
> adjustments described in [dcl.fct] are performed. [ Example: **A
> parameter type of** “void (const int, int[5])” **becomes**
> “void(*)(int,int*)”. — end example ] [...]

Note the reference to [dcl.fct] and the related (non-normative) example in /3, showing the adjustment of a value type array function parameter `int[N]` to `int*`, meaning a non-type template parameter `N` is not deducible from arguments passed to a value type array parameter (`N` is useless/ignored in this context).

Template argument deduction from a function call, particularly, is covered by [[temp.deduct.call]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.deduct.call); and the relevant section that differentiates your two examples is [[temp.deduct.call]/2.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.deduct.call#2.1), which says that if the argument of a call (denoted `A`) is an array type, and the parameter type (denoted `P`) is *not* a reference type, a pointer type is used for type deduction:

> /2 If `P` is not a reference type:
>
> - (2.1) If `A` is an array type, the pointer type produced by the array-to-pointer standard conversion is used in place of `A` for type
>   deduction; otherwise, [...]

Whereas when `P` *is* a reference type, as in the following example:

> ```
> template<class T, std::size_t n>
> std::size_t len(T (&v)[n]) { return n; }
> ```

[temp.deduct.call]/2.1 does not apply, and for the following call to a function named `len` with an array as argument

```
int arr[] = { 1,2,3 };
(void)len(arr);
```

name lookup will find the function template `len`, and template argument deduction will subsequently be applied with `P` as `T[N]` (as per [[temp.deduct.call]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.deduct.call#3.sentence-2)) and `A` as `int[3]` for the single function parameter of `len`, which deduces `T` to `int` and `N` to `3` for the complete type deduction of the parameter type `P`; as per [[temp.deduct.type]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.deduct.type#1):

> Template arguments can be deduced in several different contexts, but
> in each case a type that is specified in terms of template parameters
> (call it `P`) is compared with an actual type (call it `A`), and an
> attempt is made **to find template argument values** (a type for a type
> parameter, **a value for a non-type parameter**, or a template for a
> template parameter) that will make `P`, after substitution of the
> deduced values (call it the deduced `A`), compatible with `A`.

I.e., the non-type template parameter `N` is part of the *type* of the single function parameter (and so is the type template parameter `T`).

Answer (score 4):

In this:

```
template<class T, std::size_t n>
std::size_t len(T (&v)[n]) { return n; }
```

`v` is a *reference* to a `T[n]` array.  The size of the array (`n`) is part of the array's type.  So `n` can be deduced from any fixed-sized array that is passed in.

In this:

```
template<class T, std::size_t n>
std::size_t len(T v[n]) { return n; }
```

In a function parameter `T v[n]`, `n` is ignored, and `T v[]` is just syntax sugar for `T *v` (you can see that in the error message - `std::size_t len(T*)`).  So, there is effectively nothing to deduce `n` from, even if a fixed-length array were passed in.

Answer (score 2):

The first one is equivalent to a pointer. See **[dcl.fct](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.fct#5)** (invoked by **[temp.deduct](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.deduct)** as @dfrib's answer explains):

> The type of a function is determined using the following rules. ... After determining the type of each parameter, any parameter of type “array of `T`” ... is adjusted to be “pointer to `T`”. ...

This does not apply to the second one because it is a reference to an array (there aren't arrays of references, but references to arrays are fine).